# Difference between throwable and error in java?

Tags: java, object

Can someone explain to me the difference between Throwable and Error objects in java? I have seen code examples that use a throwable object but require an error object and vice versa and sometimes both seem to work. For example in this code:

```
public void onFailure(Error error) {
    Log.e("MyActivity", error.getMessage(), error);
}
```

vs.

```
public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
        Log.e("MyActivity", throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
}
```

Comment: `Throwable` is the highest parent class of things that can be _thrown_. It has two subclasses: `Error` (for hard errors that usually can not be recovered from, for example `OutOfMemoryError`, thrown by the JVM) and `Exception` (stuff thrown by your code, for example `FileNotFoundException`).

Comment: Please get used to reading the official Javadocs, it explains all of this. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Throwable.html

Comment: For a logger, you want to catch all sorts of issues. So you would take `Throwable`, which catches `Error`s as well as `Exception`s.

Comment: Thank you @Zabuzard, this explains a lot! I will look more in-depth at the documentation!

Answer (score 1):

If you take a further look at the javadocs, you will see that the Error class is actually derived from the Throwable class, meaning that an Error is also a Throwable, that is why you can use an Error object even if the function needs a Throwable.

An Error is a type of Throwable, which should not be caught by the developer. More info about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html

Overall, I haven't really worked with Errors at all, so I'd suggest using Throwables, since they are more abstract, meaning you can also pass an Error object into the second onFailure function if needed.

Comment: OP has a valid reason to catch `Error`s though, logging. It is perfectly reasonable to catch an `Error` for a last effort to save some information. It is just not given that all `Error`s are recoverable from or that the JVM still has enough time left to go into the `catch` block.

Comment: @Zabuzard Errors are usually not the developer's fault, since they mean low-level problems, so logging them isn't really useful for the developer. Also, as you said, the JVM might not even go to the catch block, so trying to find a non-existing log of an Error will just cause even more problems.

Comment: There are plenty of examples for real software that is actually catching `Error` on purpose to at least try to rescue something in certain situations or at least try to log what happened or why it crashed. Theres also the idiomatic example of catching `OutOfMemoryError` to then free up some bytes to then gain a little bit of extra breathing room for the shutdown and cleanup procedure.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Error is a subclass of Throwable.
Exceptions (they are also subclasses of Throwable) should be caught and handled, but Errors should not.

Comment: OP has a valid reason to catch `Error`s though, logging. It is perfectly reasonable to catch an `Error` for a last effort to save some information. It is just not given that all `Error`s are recoverable from or that the JVM still has enough time left to go into the `catch` block.